# Select Category then show Category.sizes

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Hello i have a form to create a Product. The user should be able to select the Category(e.g T-Shirt) and then all the Sizes(eg S, M, L) for the T-Shirt should drop down. The user can the input the quantity they have for each size.

**The Javascript isn't working for this. The user can select a category but the Sizes don't drop down. Can anyone see why? I know Rails but i don't know JS.**

When i inspect the view i can see in the HTML that the sizes are there.

Here is my view

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "custom" %>
<div class="container">
  <div class=“row”>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <%= simple_form_for @product_form, as: :product_form, url: products_path do |f| %>
            <%= f.collection_select :category_id, @categories, :id, :name, include_blank: true, :prompt => "Select One Category" %>
            <% @categories.each do |category| %>
              <div class='sizes_container' id ='sizes_container_for_<%= category.id %>'>
                <% category.sizes.each do |size| %>
                  <%= f.hidden_field :size_id, value: size.id %>
                  <%= size.title %>
                  <%= f.input :quantity %>
                <% end %>
              </div>
            <% end %>
            <%= f.input :title, label:"Title"%>
            <%= f.input :price, label:"Price"%>
            <%= f.input :description,label:"Description" %>
            <%= f.input :tag_list,label:"Tags - Seperate tags using comma ','. 5 tags allowed per product" %>
            <%= f.button :submit, "Create new product", class: "btn-lg btn-success" %>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the JS

```
this.products = {
  updateCategory: function() {
    var id = $('#product_category_id').val();
    $('.sizes_container').hide();
    $('#sizes_container_for_' + id).show();
  }
};

$(function() {
  products.updateCategory();
  $('#product_category_id').on('change', products.updateCategory);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it's a bad sign that you're including custom javascript in your view:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "custom" %>
```

This should be in the *layout* you're using:

```
#app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<%= javascript_include_tag :application, :custom %>
```

Whilst there's nothing wrong with what you've done, it's bad practice (fragments your JS all over your app). Further, if you wanted to really be efficient, you'd put your code into the `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` file itself:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$('document').on('change', 'select#product_category_id', function(e){
    var id = $(this).val();
    $('.sizes_container').hide();
    $('#sizes_container_for_' + id).show();
});
```

I also think it's a bit overkill to create a class for this. You're better just putting the code into a function as it is above.

--

The above should work, considering your HTML is correct. Another important note is that in Rails, you should always bind to the DOM load event in some way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).on("page:load" ...
```

This is mainly an issue with `Turbolinks`, but is also better practice than just using `$(function...`.